# Why it works when I type multiple characters in a character variable?

Tags: c++

I am a new C++ user.
My code is as following:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int option = 1;
   char abstract='a';
   while(option == 1){
     char temp;
     cin>> temp;
     abstract = temp;
     cout << abstract;
     option = 1;
     if(abstract == '!'){
         option = 0;
     }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

And when I typed something like:  abcdefg
all the characters are on the screen,why? It's just because of the compiler?

Comment: Instead of using an integer as a **flag**, consider using a `bool`, or more idiomatic, direct flow control constructs such as `break`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the `while` loop, which processes each character in turn. Not sure what you expected to happen.

Print it out with delimiters to see that there's never more than a single character printed per iteration:

```
cout << "'" << abstract << "'";
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact, only one character at a time is stored in your `char`. `cin>>temp;` reads a single char at a time since more characters would not fit there. The loop simply reads and prints one character after the other.

As a visualization hint, try echoing your characters with `cout<<abstract<<endl;`. You will see a single character per line/iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Your terminal does not restrict the number of characters typed in , that's why you can type as many as you want. Your c++ compiler would read only one of the characters because 'temp' is of type char. you can type an 'if' statement to check the number of characters typed in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

The terminal window itself is responsible for reading the characters and echoing them back to the screen. Your C++ program asks the terminal for characters and, in this sort of program at least, has no effect on how those characters are displayed.